# Figure out why OSX resolves a certain web extension locally

Tags: macos, dns, dnsmasq, lamp

I'm running OSX 10.12.6 and I've added some packages using Homebrew including components to run a local LAMP stack. For some reason, when I attempt to visit `https://archive.is`, the `.is` extension resolves locally and it sends me to my localhost's web root.

I've checked everything I can think of, including DNSMasq and its resolvers, but I haven't been able to spot why that extension resolves locally.

There is nothing in `/etc/hosts` relating to ad blocking, parental blocking, or `.is` specific entries and `dig` isn't indicating any local lookups.

How can I trace the DNS lookup on my machine to see where it's being resolved locally?

Comment: you can use dig with the trace option, [see here](https://ns1.com/blog/using-dig-trace) and dont forget to check /etc/hosts

Comment: Have you installed any `/etc/hosts`-based ad-blocking or parental-blocking entries?

Comment: Nothing in `/etc/hosts` relating to ad blocking, parental blocking, or `.is` specific entries. Added this to my original question for clarity and `dig` isn't indicating any local lookups.

Comment: What does `scutil --dns` report? What do you get if you query archive.is from `dns-sd`? What apps or tools were you using to try archive.is before? Please note that Chrome, Firefox, `nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` each bring their own DNS resolver code and thus do things differently from most of macOS and may get different results.

Comment: what happens when you stop all LAMP services?

Comment: @Zina great question, Chrome gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and FF/Safari give me similar "unable to connect" errors.

Comment: that is strange, I tested the link and it opened the web archive site, so you must have something else (outside of LAMP) which is not allowing you to connect to the site. could you check with `lsof -nP -i4TCP:443 | grep -i listen` what process is  listening on 443?